# how to use concat function with update in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

code:

```
if($this->input->post('submit'))
{

    $data = array(
            'admin_id' => $this->input->post('admin'), 
            );
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('assign_menu_admin');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        $where = "menu_link = '".$row['menu_link']."'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->set('admin_id', "CONCAT(admin_id,',','".$data."')", FALSE); 
        $query = $this->db->update('assign_menu_admin');
        echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
}
```

In this code I have a table having name assign_menu_admin and admin_id name column inside it. Now, I want to use concat function to showing my admin_id like this 1,2,3,4 but it showing error. How can I fix this error ?Please help me.

[image]

Thank You

Comment: The problem doesn't come from the MySQL `CONCAT` function, but from `$data` being an array. You have to transform it into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
$this->db->set('admin_id', "CONCAT(admin_id,',','".$data['admin_id']."')", FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find below mentioned solution.

You are passing data from php to database hence you can use `implode()` function.

**Syntax**

> **implode(separator,array)**

**Parameters**

```
separator:  Optional. Specifies what to put between the array elements. Default is "" (an empty string)
array    :  Required. The array to join to a string
```

**Solution**

```
$this->db->set('admin_id', implode(',',$this->input->post('admin')));
```

Let me know if it not works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
 $this->db->set('admin_id', implode(",", $data) ), FALSE);
```

This will glue each array value with a COMMA character together and return a string.

Output will be:

```
 $this->db->set('admin_id', '1,2,3,4', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify what you have to:

```
    //columns with data you are updating
    $data = [
       //use php implode function to turn an array into a string with each item separated by a ","
       'admin_id'=>implode(',', $this->input->post('admin'))
    ];

    //you can also cast an array of where statements as well
    $this->db->where('menu_link', $row['menu_link'])
    //table to update, followed by columns and data you are updating 
    ->update('assign_menu_admin', $data);
```

Comment: it showing error @Parker Dell when I echo  last_query  UPDATE `assign_menu_admin` SET `admin_id` = 'CONCAT(admin_id,\',\',\'Array\')' WHERE `menu_link` = 'admins/college,admins/manage'

Answer (score 0):

The `$data` that you are putting in the concat is an `array` and you can't user array like that.

Replace this line:

```
$this->db->set('admin_id', "CONCAT(admin_id,',','".$data."')", FALSE);
```

with this line:

```
$this->db->set('admin_id', "CONCAT(admin_id,',','".$data['admin_id']."')", FALSE);
```